# ARKit: Finding the coordinates of a SCNNode on the screen

Tags: ios, swift, arkit, scnnode, arscnview

I have a simple Swift ARKit setup where I have a SCNNode with a 3D object that is visible in an ARSCNView.

I want to determine the 2D coordinates of this object on the ARSCNView. By this I mean the x- and y-coordinates the object has when it is drawn onto the screen.

I have provided a sketch to illustrate what I mean:
[image: Sketch]

Is there a way to get these coordinates, or at least an approximation? I need this in order to do some further processing with the camera frame. Basically I am interested in the area the object occupies on the screen.

Comment: Did you have a look at the viewMatrix method of ARCamera? https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arcamera/2921672-viewmatrix

Comment: Isn't this what [projectPoint](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint) does?

Comment: @leandrodemarco Yes, it is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use [`SCNSceneRenderer projectPoint:point`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnscenerenderer/1524089-projectpoint) :

> Projects a point from the 3D world coordinate system of the scene to the 2D pixel coordinate system of the renderer.

```
let node:SCNNode = // Your node
let nodeWorldPosition = node.position
let nodePositionOnScreen = renderer.projectPoint(nodeWorldPosition)
let x = nodePositionOnScreen.x
let y = nodePositionOnScreen.y
```

Note : *A point projected from the near (resp. far) clip plane will have a z component of 0 (resp. 1).*

---

The same method can be used with `ARAnchor` :

```
let anchor:ARAnchor = // ...
let anchorWorldPosition = SCNVector3(anchor.transform.columns.3)
let anchorPositionOnScreen = renderer.projectPoint(anchorWorldPosition)
let x = anchorPositionOnScreen.x
let y = anchorPositionOnScreen.y
```

Comment: Is there a way to make it work with ARImageAnchor ?

Comment: `ARImageAnchor` is a subclass of `ARAnchor` so I think it should work the same, I did not test it though

Comment: Reference to member 'projectPoint' cannot be resolved without a contextual type

Comment: Note that `ARSCNView` conforms to `SCNSceneRenderer` protocol, so you can use `projectPoint:point:` method directly with your reference to `ARSCNView`.

This was not readily obvious to me as someone new to SceneKit.

Comment: this line:  let nodeWorldPosition = node.position should be: let nodeWorldPosition = node.worldPosition